# Custom button Javascript Date compare

Tags: javascript, custom-button

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")} 


var accountid= "{!Account.Id}"; 

var nowDate = new Date(); 
var d= (nowDate.getFullYear()-1)+'-'+(nowDate.getMonth()+1)+'-'+nowDate.getDate(); 
alert(d);

var RelatedOpps= sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id,Cohort_Date_Value__c,StageName from Opportunity WHERE Accountid ='{!Account.Id}' AND Cohort_Date_Value__c<"+d);

if(RelatedOpps==null){  
alert("No Opps "+RelatedOpps);
} 
else { 
alert("List of Opps "+RelatedOpps);

}
```

What I am doing: I am trying to query the Opportunity records based on Cohort_Date_Value__c value. Trying to query records where Cohort_Date_Value__c<(Today()-1 year)

Cohort_Date_Value__c: Datatype: Formula(Date): Ex:2017-02-04
d: Ex:2017-2-4

Error:
[image]

Any idea how to compare these dates?

**UPDATE: (Working)**

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")} 


var accountid= "{!Account.Id}"; 

var todaysDate = new Date();

function convertDate(date) {
  var yyyy = (date.getFullYear()-1).toString();
  var mm = (date.getMonth()+1).toString();
  var dd  = date.getDate().toString();

  var mmChars = mm.split('');
  var ddChars = dd.split('');

  return yyyy + '-' + (mmChars[1]?mm:"0"+mmChars[0]) + '-' + (ddChars[1]?dd:"0"+ddChars[0]);
}
var d = convertDate(todaysDate);
alert(d);

var RelatedOpps= sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id,Cohort_Date_Value__c,StageName from Opportunity WHERE Accountid ='{!Account.Id}' AND Cohort_Date_Value__c < " + d);

if(RelatedOpps==null){ 

alert("No Opps "+RelatedOpps);

} 
else { 

alert("List of Opps "+RelatedOpps);
records = RelatedOpps.getArray("records");

for (var i=0; i< records.length; i++) {
    var record = records[i];
    alert("Opportunity name"+ record.Name + "Contact Id -- " + record.Cohort_Date_Value__c);
  }

}
```

Comment: check my answer of simplified approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to compare with the formula Date field then, convert the today's date with proper format.

```
var d = (new Date().toISOString()).substring(0,10);
```

which will always give you `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

To retrieve last year on same date:

```
var currentDate = (new Date().toISOString()).substring(0,10);   
var yearPart = (new Date().toISOString()).substring(0,4) -1;
d = yearPart + (new Date().toISOString()).substring(4,10);
```

And then in the query, use like this:

```
var RelatedOpps= sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id,CreatedDate ,StageName from Opportunity WHERE Accountid ='{!Account.Id}' AND Cohort_Date_Value__c <" + d);
```

Your entire code will be:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")} 

var accountid= "{!Account.Id}"; 
var currentDate = (new Date().toISOString()).substring(0,10);   
var yearPart = (new Date().toISOString()).substring(0,4) -1;
d = yearPart + (new Date().toISOString()).substring(4,10); 

var RelatedOpps= sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id,Cohort_Date_Value__c,StageName from Opportunity WHERE Accountid ='{!Account.Id}' AND Cohort_Date_Value__c < " + d);
if(RelatedOpps==null){ 
    alert("No Opps "+RelatedOpps);
} 
else {     
alert("List of Opps "+RelatedOpps);
records = RelatedOpps.getArray("records");

for (var i=0; i< records.length; i++) {
    var record = records[i];
    alert("Opportunity name"+ record.Name + "Contact Id -- " + record.Cohort_Date_Value__c);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Santanu. However I need to minus one year from current date. Because I have to query the records last 365 days from today. I am trying this one "
d.setYear(d.getYear() – 1);", but it is not working

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, but I have updated any answer properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

You can use [SOQL Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) to do this without additional javascript.

From the sound of it, you'd want to use `LAST_N_DAYS:n` with 'n' replaced with 365. From the page linked above:

> For the number n provided, starts 00:00:00 of the current day and continues for the past n days.

So n = 365 gives you a date range from today, and stretches back 365 days. Finding records strictly less than this range should give you what you're looking for.

Your query would become

```
var RelatedOpps= sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id,Cohort_Date_Value__c,StageName from Opportunity WHERE Accountid ='{!Account.Id}' AND Cohort_Date_Value__c < LAST_N_DAYS:365");
```

The upside to this method is that you don't need to worry about doing date arithmetic yourself.

The downside is that leap years are probably not handled correctly.